# Entity framework code first relation generates wrong sql index code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two classes:

```
[Table("Sales.Order")]
public partial class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //conventions allow for Id property
    public int? ParentId { get; set; } //self referencing
    public virtual Order ParentOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> ChildOrders { get; set; }

    public byte? OrderRelationTypeId { get; set; }
}

[Table("Sales.OrderRelationType")]
public partial class OrderRelationType
{
    public OrderRelationType()
    {
        Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    public byte Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

and some fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
.HasMany(e => e.ChildOrders)
.WithOptional(e => e.ParentOrder)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);
```

after generating a migration + db update 
The sql has the correct tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Sales].[Order] (
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ParentId] [int],
    [OrderRelationTypeId] [tinyint],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales.Order] PRIMARY KEY ([OrderId])
)

CREATE TABLE [Sales].[OrderRelationType] (
    [OrderRelationTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales.OrderRelationType] PRIMARY KEY ([OrderRelationTypeId])
)
```

But also some wrong index creation code

```sql
ALTER TABLE [Sales].[Order] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Sales.Order_Sales.Order_ParentId] 
FOREIGN KEY ([ParentId]) REFERENCES [Sales].[Order] ([Id])
```

> Foreign key 'FK_Sales.Order_Sales.Order_ParentId' references invalid column 'Id' in referenced table 'Sales.Order'.

and

```sql
ALTER TABLE [Sales].[Order] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Sales.Order_Sales.OrderRelationType_OrderRelationTypeId] 
FOREIGN KEY ([OrderRelationTypeId]) REFERENCES [Sales].[OrderRelationType] ([Id])
```

> Foreign key 'FK_Sales.Order_Sales.OrderRelationType_OrderRelationTypeId' references invalid column 'Id' in referenced table 'Sales.OrderRelationType'.

So EF is creating the right column names, but referencing the wrong names in the index??

I do want to use Id not OrderId as property names, and I am not doing anything illegal as far as I can see.
I am using ef 6.1.3

generated migration code:

```
    CreateTable(
            "Sales.Order",
            c => new
                {
                    OrderId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    CouponId = c.Int(),
                    ParentId = c.Int(),
                    OrderRelationTypeId = c.Byte(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.OrderId)
            .ForeignKey("Sales.Order", t => t.ParentId)
            .ForeignKey("Sales.OrderRelationType", t => t.OrderRelationTypeId)
            .Index(t => t.ParentId)
            .Index(t => t.OrderRelationTypeId);

        CreateTable(
            "Sales.OrderRelationType",
            c => new
                {
                    OrderRelationTypeId = c.Byte(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.OrderRelationTypeId);
```

Comment: Can we see the generated migration file?

Comment: added generated migration code

Comment: Just to be sure - the migration is using the `OrderId` property. I noticed your class is partial. Do you have `OrderId` *and* `Id` defined for `Order`?

Comment: I only have an Id not an OrderId Property. But you got me thinking.
I generated the Poco code from an existing database.

Then Changed all EntitynameId properties to Id properties.
There already was a migration and I rerun that migration.
But that does not update the entire migration 

After using Add-Migration FirstMigration -Force
It did correctly update the migration files and also the sql